# USB 3.0 controller is not recognized

Tags: 12.04, usb

I have a Thinkpad E430 notebook, and the intel's USB 3.0 controller can not be recognized by Ubuntu 12.04.

The LED on my USB-HDD is white instead of blue (And in Windows 7, it is blue when connected to USB 3.0 port, and is white when connected to 2.0). And the transfer speed is around 25MB/s instead of 65MB/s in Windows 7.

I'm not familiar with Linux systems, so I've no clue about what's going wrong. I've searched the web, but got no solution.

Comment: You need to specify the type of hardware you have, you can pick this out using 'lspci -nn' and I would recommend having a quick look in '/var/log/dmesg' for usb 3.0 related warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a kernel upgrade to 3.5.x. You should have the possibility to install linux-image-3.5.0-18-generic from the precise-updates repository.

That move solved all my USB related problems with a 'ASRock Z77 Extreme6' motherboard with Intel chipset.